# Exclamation mark on .xlsm file

Tags: xlsm

i've prepared one excel file with Visual Basic code. It was saved with .xlsm extension. And now the excel icon is appeared with exclamation mark that is irritative.
Can I remove that exclamation mark from the icon?

Answer (score 6):

save that file with .xls extension.you can remove exclamation mark

With the introduction of Office 2007, Macro enabled worksheets saved as .XLSM files show the exclamation point as part of the icon. This is not to show that it is an error or that it is dangerous, only to inform you that it contains macros. “Feature” or not well thought out placement of punctuation? It’s completely normal, and everything is fine as long as you trust the document and/or created the document and macros yourself.